# -fopenmp flag in compile and link

Tags: compilation, linker, openmp

I have this openmp code

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  #pragma omp parallel
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "thread %d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
  }

  return 0;
}
```

when I compile and link and use the `-fopenmp`

```
gcc-6 -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -fopenmp -Iinclude -c -o build/main.o src/main.c
gcc-6 -o bin/main  build/main.o  -fopenmp
```

the code work

```
$ ./bin/main 
thread 0
thread 1
thread 2
thread 3
```

but don't when I only put the flag in the link

```
gcc-6 -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Iinclude -c -o build/main.o src/main.c
src/main.c: In function 'main':
src/main.c:6:0: warning: ignoring #pragma omp parallel [-Wunknown-pragmas]
   #pragma omp parallel
gcc-6 -o bin/main  build/main.o  -fopenmp
```

the code work but not in parallel

```
$ ./bin/main 
thread 0
```

why I need add `-fopenmp` in compile and link time?

Comment: `-fopenmp` literally *Enables handling of OpenMP directives* in gcc - and you are asking why it needs to be added to the compilation step?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> why I need add -fopenmp in compile and link time?

Because it is required *both* at compile time (to enable the `#pragma omp` handling) and at link time (to link required support libraries).